# docker-compose SQL Server avoid losing container data and connection

Tags: sql-server, docker, dockerfile

I am testing "SQL Server Express (Windows Image)" with docker and I am creating the `docker-compose` container and I connect it with SQL Operations Studio, to get the connection IP I inspect the container with `docker inspect <container name>`, and I take it of `IPAddress`.

I have been able to test SQL commands and it works well, the problem is when I stop the container, I use `docker-compose stop`, and if I run it again I use `docker-compose start`, but I have the problem that every time I run the container again, the connection IP changes and I lose what I had created in SQL Server.

How can I avoid losing the data of the created container and not having to generate a new connection again?

Comment: you should use volumes. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/
if you are using an opensource container, try to check if they have provided a `volume` parameter

Comment: if you happened to use this, use the `attach_dbs` option https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express/